# Faster/Efficient way to run large number for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I would like to run a function for generating thermometric codes inside a list. when I am inputting large range the functions takes a lot of time -

```
    def Thermo_Only(bit_size):
        lst=[]
        code=0
        for bit in xrange(bit_size):
            lst.append(code)
            code = code*8+7
        return(lst)
```

when the input is 0x3ffff I am receiving MemoryError using Pyscripter 
I have tried list comprehension but I can't seem to include -

```
 code = code*8+7
```

properly...

Comment: `0x3ffff` is `262143`. I'm surprised a list with `262143` elements causes a MemoryError.

Comment: @DeepSpace the memory error probably happens due to his `code` being too big, im not an expert on python 2 but i do recall that there was a maxint which he probably goes over

Comment: You are multiplying `code` by 8 in each iteration, so its value will exceed `8 ** 0x3ffff` which is quite large and takes a lot of memory to store. Are you sure you need to reach values this large?

Comment: @DeepSpace is correct - 'code' is being updated on each iteration, I don't know how to write it as list comprehension, for example I have tried - [code*8+7 for code in range (0x3ffff)] but it behaves differently

Comment: @DeepSpace: it's not the size of the list that's the problem here. It's the size of the list **and the exponential growth of `code`** that conspire to blow up the memory footprint.

Comment: @Nullman I was able to calculate `code` on repl: https://repl.it/repls/CoordinatedSpectacularEllipses Whever or not this value is correct is another story

Comment: A list comprehension will not safe you from the fact that `code` is growing exponentially, upwards of [8 to the power 262143](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8+to+the+power+262143).

Comment: A generator using [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) might be useful, but I'm not sure you really wanted an exponential series? That would require that you upgrade to Python 3, something I would strongly recommend *anyway*, at which point `accumulate(range(bit_size), lambda c, _: c * 8 + 7)` is a generator for the series.

Comment: @DeepSpace And were you able to store all the intermediate values of `code` in a list? That would take about 13 GB of memory.

Comment: @interjay Didn't try to. I was just testing the suggestion that the problem is with Python 2's "maxint" limit. It does look like the problem is with storing all the intermediate values of `code`.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Python 2 doesn't have a maxint limit, it transparently switches to `long`, which is the same type as `int` in Python 3.

Comment: @DeepSpace: the list comprehension to produce the same values is `[(8 ** code) - 1 for code in range(bit_size)]` (swap `range()` for `xrange()` in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

Using xrange and list comprehension really reduced the for loop slowness. I have also reduced the maximum value to 0x3fff, that seems to give me all the needed values.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be getting into memory issues with your code in Python 3.  I tried it (changing `xrange()` for `range()`) and got the response in 12 seconds.

You could write the function like this:

```
def Thermo_Only(n): 
    return [ (1<<i)-1 for i in range(0,3*n,3) ]
```

This actually allows you to avoid generating the list at all.  if you were going to place the result in an array:

```
thermoArray = Thermo_Only(n)
```

you could simply create a function instead and use it as if you were referencing indexes in your array:

```
def thermoArray(n): return (1<<(3*n))-1
```

and use `thermoArray(i)` instead of `thermoArray[i]` in your code.